# multiple queries MySQL vs PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website which has tables: movies and episodes

Every page has:

1. a list of first characters ... "what does the movie name start with ?"
2. (the admin defines the number of) most downloaded (counting downloads)
3. (the admin defines the number of) newest updates
4. if user has searched for something the search result or if the user has

selected a first character list of names starting with it ...
so what I want to ask is:
should I do a seperate query for each one of them Like:

```
1. "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY name" /* then check the first Characters */
2. "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY downloads_count DESC LIMIT :lim", array(":lim"=>NUMBER_TO_SHOW)
3. "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT :lim", array(":lim"=>NUMBER_TO_SHOW)
4. "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY WHERE name LIKE :char name LIMIT :start, :end", array(":char"=>$first_char."%", ":start"=>$page_starting_number, ":end"=>$page_ending_number)
```

, or should I fech names and sort them every time I and check for first characters match with a `foreach(){}` ?

which one puts lower pressure on the server (because the server I'm programming for is a busy one and I really don't like to blow it up ... :|)
(and I've heard about mysql caching ... how reliable is it ?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better do it in the queries, because the database system is optimised to do this. And for queries that occurs repeatedly you can use `Memcached` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... but could you please explain the diffrence more if you know ... for people coming here from now on

Comment: Database uses indexes for searching, this way it can find quickly data related to a given id, it doesn't must iterate over the full list like php, so it is much faster. The memcached stores the results in memory, so you don't need to query the results more time (if the query or the database are not updated)